# "Winclone has been discontinued". Now what?

Tags: snow-leopard, bootcamp, hard-drive

I just **replaced my old 320Gb HHD** on my MBP with a **240Gb SSD** and I **did not wanted to transfer the hole drive** as it would not fit, as I have more than 60Gb of music and 110Gb of Photos and HD Videos.

So I started "blank" and, might say, did a good job :o)

but I really want to have my Bootcamp partition on my SSD instead hooking up the HHD all the time, and was searching for a tool...

**Carbon Copy Cloner** sounded great but:

[image]

then searching the forums I got **Winclone** and that was exactly what I wanted, but ... again

- website is no longer available
- Goggle cache page reported: "Winclone has been discontinued"

[image]

What are my options now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good news is that **[CNET Downloads](http://download.cnet.com)** still have the file on their own server so, we can easily get it form there

[Winclone 2.2 on CNET Downloads](http://download.cnet.com/Winclone/3000-2242_4-172338.html?tag=mncol)

and after that the beauty come to us!

[image]

Unfortunately, WinClone will not work under OSX Lion...

Comment: CNET now just redirects to twocanoes.com; they don't seem to host the older version any more.

Answer (score 2):

Winclone 3 is out. $19.99. Works with Windows Vista or 7. XP unsupported, but sometimes works. OSX 10.6+

http://twocanoes.com/winclone.php

Comment: Winclone is still kicking and at version 4.4!